# NSImage initWithContentsOfFile returns nil

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, osx-yosemite

Hello I'm trying to load an image to NSImage from files, but aImage is always nil. What am I doing wrong here?

```
NSImage * aImage = [[NSImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile: @"/Users/Thilina/Desktop/Other/20140818_163933_Fotor_Collage.jpg" ];
[imgPic setImage:aImage];
```

Comment: "The filename parameter should include the file extension that identifies the type of the image data. This method looks for an NSImageRep subclass that handles that data type from among those registered with NSImage."

Comment: Can you please give an example. Because there's no such method. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example.

```
- (void)getMyImage {
    NSImage *img = [self getImage:filePath];
}

- (NSImage *)getImage:(NSString *)path {
    NSArray *imageReps = [NSBitmapImageRep imageRepsWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSInteger width = 0;
    NSInteger height = 0;
    for (NSImageRep * imageRep in imageReps) {
        if ([imageRep pixelsWide] > width) width = [imageRep pixelsWide];
        if ([imageRep pixelsHigh] > height) height = [imageRep pixelsHigh];
    }
    NSImage *imageNSImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:NSMakeSize((CGFloat)width, (CGFloat)height)];
    [imageNSImage addRepresentations:imageReps];
    return imageNSImage;
}
```